Storing locally on Git: do I still need to push?
I want to use Git for version control, so my setup would be to just have a local Git (no GitHub or anything). I can then add/change files with git add and git commit. From previous experience with GitHub I know that you have to git push to upload my files and 'finalize' the commit.
Is it still necessary to push to my local git? Or is committing enough?

If there's no remote, there's nowhere to push to. I usually keep a (bare) remote on a USB stick and I need to push to it, then.

If you learned to write (with a pen) only through writing (and posting) letters...... then would you also need to put everything you ever write in a mailbox? Your grocery list too? Come on.

@choroba Thanks that basically answers my question

Maybe the strange "finalize the commit" statement?

Does this answer your question? What are the differences between "git commit" and "git push"?

You do not have to use git push if you are not using a remote repository (like GitHub, GitLab, etc.). You can see git push as more for sharing while git commit is for history/checkpoint.
You should watch git's own official tutorials.

If you are just in local, no, you don't need to push.
You will have your working directory, and your branches and commits in the .git sub-directory.
(Note that there are gui tools which can help you manage your local git repository :

you can use gitk for example to see your branches and commits and easily rebase your working directory to the state of any commit
with git gui for example you can check what files were changed since your last commit, and add the changes to a new commit)



'finalize' the commit

Git doesn't mandate any repository role, that's entirely up to you. You decide if any repository will be administered as "final" published commits. If there's some repo you've decided is your publishing repo, then you need to push (or fetch) your commits there to finalize them.

It's correct thought I would object to the use of the word finalize over here. Sounds like there's something pending about commits if you do not push them.... Not the case.

@eftshift0 I hear you on that, No commit is intrinsically any more or less permanent than any other, but my workflow tends to treat anything I haven't pushed as a first draft, commit status like everything else about whatever's in any repo is entirely up to the repo administrator. If you administer a repo as for-first-drafts-until-they're-somewhere-else-too, then that's what's there. It's a personal thing, my early attempts tend to be crude and needing some polish, rework or even rethink. Nobody needs to see those but sometimes they still do.
